# TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined in react while running npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am encountering this problem when I am running my react app I can someone help me on this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
This is the error on the browser page 
The terminal tells this:


./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I am stuck due to this error please help!

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you with this. Are you using create-react-app? The error seems to originate from webpack-dev-server, which likely uses express (a nodejs web framework) under the hood. This doesn't seem to be related to React itself. What's in your package.json? Did you run npm install or yarn install before trying to start the project?

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Answer (score -1):

I found that I have wrong typed

import response from { 'express' }

I found that this issue happens when you call backEnd stuff in the frontEnd.
When I delete that line issue solved.

It turns out that I didn't type the import statement because I used the word response as a variable name, it was automatically imported.
I'm not sure if the import was from React itself or another VS code auto-completion extension.